# Error con System.Runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo un proyecto ASP.Net Framework 4.8 que al iniciarse, arroja este mensaje:

```sh
[BadImageFormatException: No se puede cargar un ensamblado de referencia para la ejecución.]

[BadImageFormatException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'System.Runtime' ni una de sus dependencias. Los ensamblados de referencia no deben cargarse para la ejecución. Se pueden cargar únicamente en el contexto de cargador solo para la reflexión. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80131058)]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +37
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +159
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +80
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +22
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +29
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +39

[ConfigurationErrorsException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'System.Runtime' ni una de sus dependencias. Los ensamblados de referencia no deben cargarse para la ejecución. Se pueden cargar únicamente en el contexto de cargador solo para la reflexión. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80131058)]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +777
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +229
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +140
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +176
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +99
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +310
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +165
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +590

[HttpException (0x80004005): No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'System.Runtime' ni una de sus dependencias. Los ensamblados de referencia no deben cargarse para la ejecución. Se pueden cargar únicamente en el contexto de cargador solo para la reflexión. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80131058)]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10086640
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +99
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +263
```

Ya intenté agregar el componente `System.Runtime` pero el error persiste... ¿podrían darme una mano?

Saludos!

Comment: ¿Qué valor tienen los `<RequiredTargetFramework>` dentro de tu `.csproj`?

Comment: Te recomendaría que mire https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask para qué tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, haz el recorrido para entender como funciona obtener tu primera medalla http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges

Comment: `BadImageFormatException` suele referirse que la aplicacion esta compilada para 64 bits y alguna dll es de 32, o viceversa...

Comment: @jachguate el valor <RequiredTargetFramework> no existe, pero existe éste otro: <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>

Comment: Gracias @DanyParedes revisaré el post que me sugieres para mejorar mi interacción. Por cierto "Qué" se acentúa sólo cuando es una exclamación o interrogación... no cuando se usa en función de un pronombre relativo. Digo, veo que corregiste mi "éste" por "este" aún cuando la RAE acepta ambas opciones.

Comment: Gracias @Pikoh me diste una buena idea, no había indagado esa opción, la revisaré.

Comment: @Pikoh, ya revisé, y pues todos los proyectos están en configuración "Any CPU" por lo que deduzco que no es por ahí :( Gracias.

Comment: Solo por descartar..intenta cambiar el framework.net de destino, a ver si te sigue dando el mismo error. Tambien es importante que revises si tienes paquetes nuget

Comment: Gracias @Pikoh ya había realizado esa prueba, hice un downgrade a 4.7.2 y el problema persiste. Efectivamente tengo Nugets y de hecho intenté instalar el componente System.Runtime pero sin éxito... :(

Comment: ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre esta pregunta y tu pregunta anterior?

Comment: Hola @Alfabravo Retiré de la solución los proyectos que comenté anteriormente y que no están relacionados con éste proyecto, ésto me cambio el error, ya no aparece la referencia con SrvOdyssey pero sigue sin funcionar cuando se supone que debería volver a su estado anterior.

Comment: Comprueba las referencias que tienes a *assemblies* del sistema y asegúrate de que no tengan activa la opción de copiar hacia la carpeta de los binarios al compilar. Prueba después a borrar las carpetas `bin` y `obj` de cada proyecto y volver a compilar.

Comment: Gracias @V.Lorz estoy en proceso con lo de tu recomendación... ahora te aviso.

Comment: Pufa!!! funcionó!!... Mil gracias @V.Lorz!!!... Sólo un detalle, al establecer todos los ensamblados de System en "No copiar" me dió un error con el de "System.Web.Optimization" y tuve que volver a ponerlo en "true" y ahí, vualá!!... volvió a correr de lo lindo! Mil gracias!!

Comment: Gabo: no olvides colocar _como respuesta_ (y luego [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer)) lo que finalmente ayudó a resolver tu problema. Así, tu pregunta no se relanzará al inicio.